# android maps not showing map

Tags: android, maps

I got api key properly . even map does not show on emulator or device.

Comment: Check the Log cat. Whats the stack trace?

Comment: have you added uses-library in manifest file??

Answer (score 0):

Internet connection permission missing?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```